# Get Score with NHibernate.Search

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I'm currently trying to use NHibernate.Search, but i need to get score for each results returned by the query.

Anyone know something about how to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using projections you can do this by having one of the properties that you are projecting to be a ProjectionConstants.SCORE reference. This will cause lucene to return values stored in the index than making a query to the database. The query will return an arraylist of object[] values instead of objects.

for example.

```
IFullTextQuery query = search.CreateFullTextQuery("query goes here");

query.SetProjection("FirstName", "LastName", ProjectionConstants.SCORE);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but actually i retrive my objects with NHibernate.Search with the List<T>() method, so can i still use List<T> with projections ?

Comment: There is no other way to automatically obtain a score using NHibernate.Search without using projections.

Comment: Any chance you could post or point to a full example of this?